# Change both value in map and reference in closure in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, closures

Well technically this is TypeScript, but the issue is a thing with JS.

I have an interface called `Animal`, like so:

```
interface Animal {
    name: string;
    speak(): void;
}

function animal(name: string): Animal {
    return {
        name,
        speak() {
            console.log('This animal does not know how to speak!');
        },
    };
}
```

I have another interface, `Dog`, which extends `Animal` and has an accompanying function that extends a regular object and makes it a `Dog`.

```
interface Dog extends Animal {
    breed: string;
}

function dog<T extends Animal>(animal: T, breed: string): T & Dog {
    const obj = {
        breed,
        ...animal,
        speak() {
            console.log(`${obj.name} says Woof!`);
        },
    };

    return obj;
}
```

I also have another interface called `Competition`, to represent all animals that participate in a competition. This is not limited to dogs.

```
interface Competition extends Animal {
    prize: number;
}

function competition<T extends Animal>(animal: T, prize: number): T & Competition {
    return {
        prize,
        ...animal,
    };
}
```

It's all fine till here. But now, I need a `Map` that stores an animal and also the name of its owner (assuming that one person can own only one animal).

```
const map: Map<string, Animal> = new Map();
```

Now there's a guy named John, and he has a Siberian Husky named Foo.

```
map.set('John', dog(animal('Foo'), 'Siberian Husky'));
```

John makes Foo join a competition, and Foo wins the second place.

```
map.set('John', competition(map.get('John'), 2));
```

However, at the competition, John sees that another dog is also named Foo, and so decides to rename his dog.

```
map.get('John').name = 'Timmy';
map.get('John').speak(); // Foo says Woof!
```

The problem is that `speak` accesses the `name` of an object that is in the closure at the time of me calling `dog(...)`, in this case, `"Foo"`. Changing the value of the variables in the object doesn't modify the value in the closure.

My question is, how do I change the value in the closure too? I can't seem to think of a way that doesn't require heavy changes to my current system.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20speak()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20animal(name%3A%20string)%3A%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20name%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20speak()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('This%20animal%20does%20not%20know%20how%20to%20speak!')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Dog%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20breed%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20dog%3CT%20extends%20Animal%3E(animal%3A%20T%2C%20breed%3A%20string)%3A%20T%20%26%20Dog%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20breed%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...animal%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20speak()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%60%24%7Bobj.name%7D%20says%20Woof!%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20obj%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Competition%20extends%20Animal%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prize%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20competition%3CT%20extends%20Animal%3E(animal%3A%20T%2C%20prize%3A%20number)%3A%20T%20%26%20Competition%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20prize%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...animal%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20map%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20Animal%3E%20%3D%20new%20Map()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Amap.set('John'%2C%20dog(animal('Foo')%2C%20'Siberian%20Husky'))%3B%0D%0Amap.get('John').speak()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Amap.set('John'%2C%20competition(map.get('John')%2C%202))%3B%0D%0Amap.get('John').name%20%3D%20'Timmy'%3B%0D%0Amap.get('John').speak()%3B%0D%0A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the methods context, `this.name` instead of `obj.name` (be careful with `this` in Typescript, the typing might not be accurate due to the way JavaScript works).

Comment: Thanks, I refrained from using `this` because VSCode's autocomplete didn't work with `this`, so I thought it referred to `window`. +1